# When I move to Fourth tab page from first one, It reloads every tab while it's moving!! on Xamarin.forms Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, android-appcompat

I'm making app with using Xamarin.forms PCL. 
I'm using Appcompat toolbar and tabs for Android.

It looks great but the problem is,
When I move to Fourth tab page from first one, It reloads every tabs while it's moving!! (2th, 3rd tab)

It causes big frame skip.

How can make it to slide to fourth tab without showing middle tabs?

I looked Youtube app, it does not seem to show middle tabs while it's moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's native behaviour, it will pre-render nearby tabs; so for your instance, in Tab1, it renders Tab2, and when you go Tab 4, it also renders Tab3.

Similar questions are answered here
[Fragment in TabLayout only load when user slide Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486841/fragment-in-tablayout-only-load-when-user-slide-android)

[Stop Android TabLayout loading next page automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353560/stop-android-tablayout-loading-next-page-automatically)